# Unable to get Android HamBurger in actionBar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

This is what my code looks like, my activity extends Activity.  I am having trouble getting the Hamburger menu icon as i get back arrow menu icon. which i dont want.

code in mainactivity:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    menu_list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_options));
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(menu_list);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer ,R.string.app_name,  R.string.app_name);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

code in action_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#29ABE2" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="DataVision" />

</LinearLayout>
```

additional methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle
    // If it returns true, then it has handled
    // the nav drawer indicator touch event
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }

    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Comment: mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer ,R.string.app_name,  R.string.app_name); this line aint working at all.,for that mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer); n even this doesnt work i dont know what m i doin wrong or missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your existing LinearLayout in a DrawerLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

then your LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#29ABE2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        etc. 
           ... 

</LinearLayout>
```

then the drawer:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

see also: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html